# Composer failing with php version when --no-dev is passed

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a composer file with a dev-dependency that requires PHP >= 5.4.0.  When I update on production (a 5.3 install (yes - I know!)) and explicitly pass the `--no-dev` option, composer still checks for the PHP version requirements from the dev packages.

Composer file:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "./vendor/"
    },
    "require": {
        "symfony/config" : "dev-master",
        "twig/twig": "1.15.1",
        "leafo/lessphp": "v0.4.0",
        "simplepie/simplepie": "dev-master",
        "contao/idna": "dev-master",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.3.*@dev",
        "james-heinrich/getid3": "dev-master",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "v2.1.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.9.1",
        "pimple/pimple": ">1.0.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "1.0.3",
        "raven/raven": "dev-curl-async",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~1.0",
        "guzzle/guzzle": "3.9.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "2.1.*@dev"
    }
}
```

`Codeception` has a requirement for PHP 5.4.0+ and when I run `composer update --no-dev` I get the following:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for codeception/codeception 2.1.*@dev -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.1.x-dev].
    - codeception/codeception 2.1.x-dev requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
```

Should composer be skipping the requirements checks for packages I've explicitly told it not to install?  I have tried passing `--ignore-platform-reqs` but without success.

**UPDATE**

It appears that running it on PHP 5.3.10 completely ignores the `--no-dev` option and reports that it is installaling them:

```
composer update --no-dev
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for codeception/codeception 2.1.*@dev -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.1.x-dev].
    - codeception/codeception 2.1.x-dev requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--no-dev` to not install the dev packages.

Comment: That is what I was trying. I stupidly typed the wrong parameter in the question - I put `--no-deps` when it should have been `--no-dev`.  Question is updated now. Thanks for your help @wouter-j

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!!!**

It appears my `composer` file was a bash script that wasn't passing the parameters to the `composer.phar` file correctly.

This problem was of my own creation.

Comment: for future referance: recommend installing composer globally via the install instructions to prevent custom script issues